# Use multiple data sources within a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper server, which holds some reports. These reports I can access by the Rest interface (https, get). One of the reports should return some data from an Oracle database, where data are stored into multiple schemas. The schemas have an identical structure.

```
select * from schemaA.tableX
```

displays the data from schemaA. Now I have to change the report data source:

```
select * from schemaB.tableX
```

to display the data from schemaB (structure of tableX is the same as in schemaA). I would like to configure my report with a parameter, to switch between the schemas (there are a lot of such schemas into the database).

Is it possible to change the schema name within the report dynamically or can I change the datasource definition of the report using a report parameter? I would prevent n identical reports on the Jasper server which only differ in the datasource definition.

Thank you.

Comment: You can pass the table/schema name as parameter if the structure of table the same

Comment: Please check the link. [Dynamic database switch](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v601/attributes-data-source-definitions) This might help you.